# ActiveMQ 5.9.0 topic separator - Cannot get destinationPathSeparatorPlugin to work

Tags: activemq-classic

Using activeMQ version 5.9.0 we want to use forward slash characters as our topic separator but when we publish on a topic these are converted to a "." (dot / period)

We tried specifying this in the config file (activemq.xml)

```
<plugins>
    <destinationPathSeparatorPlugin pathSeparator="x" />
</plugins>
```

But whatever we try does not seem to make any difference.

Comment: Are they really converted so that the subscriber has to subscribe using . instead of /?

Comment: No - the subscriber subscribes using the forward slash character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<plugins>
    <destinationPathSeparatorPlugin />
</plugins>
```

This did actually work, but ActiveMQ console still displays it using "." character !

Comment: ActiveMQ console does not always show 100% of total picture - but rather a consolish-view of the world. The best thing is to actually test using real clients.

Comment: Yes and it is not really clear what is the effect of that plugin, is it overriding the `.` or replacing it?